# How to display Base.64 image string obtained after volley call

Tags: android, android-glide

I get an image as base64 string, as a response to a webservice call in JSONArray format. I need to display this in an imageView in my MainActivity. I tried using **Glide**, but it doesn't display the image. I'm converting Base64 String to byte [] then load that byte into glide.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong here. But I couldn't find it.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String imageBytes;
ImageView picView;
RequestQueue requestQueue2 ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    picView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView) ;
    PIC__WEB_CALL();

}
public void PIC__WEB_CALL(){

    String HTTP_SERVER_URL= String.format("http://192.1.1.1/Pic/001");

    JsonArrayRequest jsArrRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, HTTP_SERVER_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    PIC_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }){

    };


    requestQueue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue2.add(jsArrRequest);

}



public void  PIC_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        Log.i("COURT", "Kooi");

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);


            imageBytes=(json.getString("Pic"));

            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(Base64.decode(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT))
                    .into(picView);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    if (array.length() != 0) {

//.....
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode your base 64 string to byte[] and then convert to Bitmap

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 
0,decodedString.length);
picView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

Comment: With glide it should work too.
Do you get error or nothing happening?

Comment: Do you using Glide 4? Try to use .asBitmap() before .load()

Comment: Yes, I'm using Glide 4 and tried asBitmap before load.